# Property order in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to write my own Spring Boot starter and let it inherit from another starter (let's say spring-boot-starter-batch). Now I want to set one of spring-boot-starter-batch properties to a default that differs from spring-boot-starter-batch's default (for example `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` instead of true). The user of my starter shall still be able to override it via `application.properties`.

That's not really possible, right? The order for reading properties is the following:

1. Command line arguments.
2. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
3. OS environment variables.
4. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`
5. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that only has properties in `random.*`.
6. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes.
7. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` including YAML and profile variants).
8. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` including YAML and profile variants).
9. Default properties (specified using `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).

So if I use `@PropertySource` in my starter to set the property, the user of my starter won't be able to override it via `application.properties`. Wouldn't it make sense to change the order and set `@PropertySource` at number 8?

Or is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Property order has been changed thanks to Dave Syer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b75578d99c8d435e1f8bf18d0dbb3a2ddf56fdc4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of `@PropertySource` is definitely up for debate. Before that debate though you should be able to add your own property sources in a listener or initializer (like the existing config file listener).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I opened a ticket for the debate: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1044